# Get a virtual field from protected, not selected field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a phone field in my user. the thing is that I can't send it to front (security and all). So I wanted to do a virtual field to know if this user has given his phone.

Here schema:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    phone: { type: String}
},{
    toObject: {virtuals: true },
    toJSON: {virtuals: true }
});
```

Here virtual:

```js
userSchema.virtual('hasPhone')
    .get(function () {
        return Boolean(this.phone);
    })
```

And I have this to select fields:

```js
const publicFields = ['-phone'];

userSchema.statics.publicOnly = function (queryObject) {
    return queryObject.select(publicFields);
}
```

And use it like so:

```js
getUserById(userId, all = false) {
    const query = User.findById(userId);

    return (!all ? User.publicOnly(query) : query).exec();
}
```

If I send all = true in it, I get the phone.

So, in my select, I exclude phone, but in that case, the virtual don't have phone anymore and cannot work.

My objective is to have hasPhone while still protecting phone

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Query with phone and use `toObject()` to convert the document to JS object. Then remove phone filed from the object. Then return the object to client.

Example:

```
const users = await userSchema.find({});
const usersObj = users.toObject();
usersObj.forEach(doc => {
  doc.phone = undefined;
})
res.end(usersObj);
```

Comment: Actually, I need both, with phone and without. I edited my question to show how I access it. So I can't use your answer since I can't select what I want.